C# windows forms как сгруппировать несколько picture box в одну группу чтобы не тратить время на каждого,
Делаю лабиринт. Хочу все вместе объединить препятствия чтобы код не писать для каждого. Пытался через pannel, groupbox, ничего не понял. Можете мне объяснить на простом примере пожалуйста.

А зачем для каждого свой код? Код можно один и тот же использовать для разных объектов.

Я как раз таки и хочу сделать, но писать для каждого один и тот же такое себе. Я хочу объединить все 27 под один, чтобы время не убивать и не засорять код.

Да не надо для этого код копировать, можно один и тот же код использовать в разных компонентах разными способами без копирования. Например, с помощью наследования. Panel - это не про код, это про группировку элементов в UI. Хотя можно конечно в коде панели обрабатывать все ваши элементы в цикле или ещё как, это да. Вот пример добавления много PictureBox в одну Panel: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37212952/8324991

Но вообще лучше сразу начните учить Unity 3D и не мучайтесь с ручной обработкой объектов. Для игр лучше специальный фреймворк использовать.

@CrazyElf поверь, в Unity там ещё сложнее в такие элементарные штуки вникать. Это только кажется, что легко.

Не в тему вопроса, но в тему лабиринтов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1512809/373567

Гляньте старый туториал Create a Maze

@aepot Я когда только учил C#, пробовал программировать Arcanoid на PictureBox-ах, вроде вполне получалось, не вижу проблем с PictureBox-ами. Хотя понятно, что логика должна быть не в них, они просто контейнеры для картинок. Много лет спустя пробовал тот же Arcanoid писать на Unity 3D, не помню, чтобы это было сильно сложнее. Хотя предварительной подготовки там больше, конечно, но зато следующие игры уже гораздо проще будет писать, чем на WinForms )

@CrazyElf пикчабокс это по сути спрайт. А если надо нарисовать зелёный прямоугольник - рисуй прямоугольник.
